# Display comment box to the author of the node being referenced using panels

Tags: 7, entities

I am creating a project that needs ONLY the author of a node being referenced AND the author of the referencing node to participate on comments on the referencing node, a sort of customer support Question/Answer system where ONLY the node author of the referencing node and the node author of the referenced node can participate in the comments section. I am implementing this with panels.

So far i can show the comment block only to the referencing node author (Question author) using the following code which checks to see if node-author-id = logged-in-user id:

```
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = arg(1);

  // Load the node if you need to
  $node = node_load($nid);
}

if($node->uid == $user->uid){
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

How do i also display this comment box to the author of the node being referenced?

**Please note:** The Question Content type and Answer Content type are two different content types

Thanks.

ps: I know about the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module as well as the [Question/Answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/question_answer) modules. Somehow the best answer submodule included with the [Answers7.x-4.0-rc2](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module is able to let the author of the question flag an answer referencing his question as the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database query would help you.

```
function my_module_get_author_by_nid($node_nid) {
  $author = '';
  if (is_numeric($node_nid) && $node_nid != 0) {
    $uid = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('uid'))
        ->condition('nid', $node_nid, '=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchField();
    return $uid;
  }
}
```

// And then a slight change in your code

```
    global $user;
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      // Get the nid
      $nid = arg(1);

      // Load the node if you need to
      $node = node_load($nid);
    }

     // Get Reference Node Nid
    $reference_nid = $node->your_reference_field_name[$node->language][0]['target_id'];
    // Get Author for reference Node
   $reference_author =  my_module_get_author_by_nid($reference_nid);
    if($node->uid == $user->uid || $user->uid == $reference_author){
      return TRUE;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: I'll try the code and mark your answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code but it only displays the pane to the author of the node being viewed, but not also to the author of the referenced node

Comment: you have to replace the reference field with your field machine name $reference_nid = $node->your_reference_field_name[$node->language][0]['target_id'];

Comment: yes i did, my entity reference field machine name is: field_referenced_question

Comment: are you getting UID returned from the my_module_get_author_by_nid() ? Ensure you are getting referenced node nid by debugging $node.

Comment: yes debugging prints the uid and name of the node author referencing the other node. It doesnt print the uid of the author of the node being referenced.

Comment: the function expects node id of referenced node not name, are you providing node id?

Comment: Apologies, couldn't place what was exactly wrong, but it works now, flawlessly. Thanks a bunch. I have selected your answer.